# find the annual percentage interest rate - ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have deposited $1000$ dollars in my account such that the interest rate is continuously compounded.

In 15 years I have $15,000$ dollars.

I have to find the annual percentage interest rate.

My try :

The appropriate ode is $y'(x)=a(x)y(x)$  when $a(x)$  is the continuously compounded interest rate.

The solution of this ode is $y(x)=e^{\int_{x_0}^{x}a(x)}$.

The initial value of this problem : $y(0)=1000,y(15)=15,000.$

Then , $y(0)=e^{\int_{x_0}^{x}a(0)}=1000,y(15)=e^{\int_{x_0}^{x}a(15)}=15,000.$

How to find the annual percentage interest rate.

Thanks !

Comment: Hint : by the usual definition of continuous compounding during the interval $[0,T]$ we deposit $D$ at time $0$ and have in $T$ years $De^{rT}$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The appropriate ode is $y'(x)=a(x)y(x)$  when $a(x)$  is the
> continuously compounded interest rate.

We have to assume that $a(x)$ is constant $r$. Then the differential equation becomes

$$\frac1{y}\cdot y^{'}=r$$

$$\frac1{y}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=r$$

$$\frac1{y} \, dy=r \, dx$$

Integrating both sides

$$\int \frac1{y} \, dy= \int r \, dx$$

$$\ln(y)=r \cdot x +c$$

$$y=e^{rx+c}=C\cdot e^{rx}$$

With $y(0)=1000$ we obtain $C=1000$. Thus the equation is $15000=1000\cdot  e^{r\cdot 15}$. It remains to solve the equation for $r$, the continuous interest rate.